# Parsing error on hibernate

Tags: hibernate

I m very new to hibernate , i  have created a very basic example but as i try to run this application xml parsing error is coming . I have create a package for resource in which i have kept the `Employee.hbm.xml` and under the src folder in eclipse i have kept the `hibernate.cfg.xml`

This is my error

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.hibernate.cfg.Environment).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.HibernateException: problem parsing configuration/com/nousinfo/resource
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.nousinfo.tutorial.utils.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:17)
    at com.nousinfo.tutorial.utils.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:7)
    at com.nousinfo.tutorial.dao.impl.EmployeeDAO.<clinit>(EmployeeDAO.java:15)
    at main.hibernatetest.main(hibernatetest.java:30)
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: problem parsing configuration/com/nousinfo/resource
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1222)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1161)
    at com.nousinfo.tutorial.utils.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:12)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: org.dom4j.DocumentException: Error on line 1 of document  : Content is not allowed in prolog. Nested exception: Content is not allowed in prolog.
    at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:350)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1217)
    ... 5 more
```

This is my hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping 
PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD//EN" 
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">


<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name=hibernate.dialect ">
            org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
        </property-name>
            <property name=hibernate.connection.driver_class ">
                com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
            </property-name>
                <property name=hibernate.connection.url ">
                    jdbc:mysql://192.168.25.30:3306/employee
                </property-name>
                    <property name=hibernate.connection.username ">
                        jack
                    </property-name>
                        <property name=hibernate.connection.password ">
                            jack1234
                        </property-name>
                            <property name="show_sql">
                                true
                            </property>

                            <property name="connection.autocommit">
                                true
                            </property>
                            <!-- List of XML mapping files -->
                            <mapping resource="com/nousinfo/resource/Employee.hbm.xml" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

This is my Employee.hbm.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping 
PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD//EN" 
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="Employee" table="EMPLOYEE">
        <meta attribute="class-description">
            This class contains the employee detail
        </meta>
        <id name="employeeNumber" type="int" column="EMPLOYE_NUMBER">
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
        <property name="firstName" type="string" column="FIRST_NAME" />
        <property name="lastName" type="string" column="LAST_NAME" />
        <property name="title" type="string" column="TITLE" />
        <property name="departmentId" type="string" column="DEPARTMENT_ID" />
        <property name="address1" type="string" column="ADDRESS_1" />
        <property name="address2" type="string" column="ADDRESS_2" />
        <property name="city" type="string" column="CITY" />
        <property name="state" type="string" column="STATE" />
        <property name="pincode" type="int" column="PINCODE" />
        <property name="telephoneNumber" type="int" column="TELEPHONE_NUMBER" />
        <property name="mobileNumber" type="int" column="MOBILE_NUMBERr" />
        <property name="dateOfBirth" type="date" column="DATE_OF_BIRTH" />
        <property name="dateOfAnniversary" type="date" column="DATE_OF_ANNIVERSARY" />
        <property name="dateOfJoining" type="date" column="DATE_OF_JOINING" />
        <property name="dateOfLeaving" type="date" column="DATE_OF_LEAVING" />
        <property name="reasonForLeaving" type="string" column="REASON_FOR_LEAVING" />
    </class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: Try to remove first space in your Employee.hbm.xml file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this exception as

1. You haven't put opening quotes (") after `name =` in many lines in hibernate configuration file.
2. You have ended a `property` tag with `property-name` tag in multiple lines of hibernate configuration file.
3. Properties are not specified completely in hibernate configuration file.

Besides these, you hibernate configuration file is full of syntax errors. Refer the following link on how to prepare hibernate configuration file.

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html